# What's the jQuery way of constantly listening to list count and modifying behaviour accordingly?

Tags: jquery

So let's say there's an element in my DOM tagged with the id `hide_me`.

When `$("ul").length` is 0, I want `hide_me` to be hidden, and when it's greater than that, I want it to be available.

`li` elements get added and removed from the DOM dynamically.

How can I implement something like this?

Comment: use an interval and do the necessary actions inside it

Comment: Interval seems like a choppy way of doing it. I was hoping there was a more eloquent solution using `.on` or something of that nature.

Comment: Depending on your browser support scope, you may be able to use `MutationObserver` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Or, you know, you could just do the check in whatever part of the code adds or removes elements from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it's hard to suggest much, but one solution would be to wire up a callback to whatever function you are using to dynamically add/remove `li`'s

consider this code:

```
var dynamicallyChangeList = {

    remove: function($li)
        {
            //where $li is a prewrapped jquery object
            $li.remove();
            this.checkHide();
        },
    add: function($ul, li)
    {
        //where $ul is a prewrapped jquery object, li is some html e.g. ("<li>Some Text</li>")
        $ul.append(li);
        this.checkHide();
    },
    checkHide: function()
    {
        var hidden = $("ul").css("display") === "none";
        if(hidden)
        {
            if($("ul > li").length > 0)
            {
                $("ul").show();
            }
        } else {

            if($("ul > li").length < 1)
            {
                $("ul").hide(); 
            }
        }
    }
};

var $li = $("#myLi");

//implement

dynamicallyChangeList.remove($li);
```

There are other, quicker and cleaner ways to do this, I am just suggesting one way.

A cleaner option (that lends itself to decoupling) is a Client Side Messaging solution like Sub/Pub or Mediator.

As you suggested in your comments you could use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) like :

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) 
{   
    alert(param1 + "\n" + param2 ); 
}); 
$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", ["Custom", "Event" ] );
```

But you're still going to have to wrap the `trigger()` call in an expression like the one above so you know when to call it.

Otherwise, There are some fantastic JS native plugins like [`postal.js`](https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js/) and some jQuery ones I have not tried such as [`Publish/Subscribe`](http://www.novasoftware.com/download/jquery/publish-subscribe.aspx)